# saving selected value from listview or checkbox

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, listview, checkbox

I was wondering if someone could help me in the right direction.
How could i save what a user has selected from list view items or a checkbox? When views are switched selected values are not saved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class. It's the standard way to say things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want to do yet SharedPreferences are always an easy way to persistence. Just be aware that these values are live beyond the lifetime of the application so you might want to delete them when the application is created again (during onCreate of your Application class for example)